# Great Expectations: Supported Expectation Types and their Arguments

Tags: python, great-expectations

I am currently working with Great Expectations (version) to build a dashboard on top to interactively provide the expectation configuration.

As an example, the JSON version of the expectation might look like this:

```py
from great_expectations.core.expectation_configuration import ExpectationConfiguration    

expectation_configuration = ExpectationConfiguration(
expectation_type = "expect_column_values_to_be_in_set",
kwargs = {
        "column": "col_a",
        "value_set": ["test"],
    },
)
```

Instead of coding this, I want to provide a dashboard to provide this information.

In order to prevent hardcoding of variables, I am currently trying to gather the following information programmatically:

- List of all expectation types.
- Which of these are available for Pandas and and which for Spark.
- For each type, the possible arguments and their type (in the end, computationally for the arguments also listed in the expectation catalog, e.g., [here](https://greatexpectations.io/expectations/expect_column_values_to_be_in_set)).

One partial idea is currently is to use `ExpectationConfiguration.kwarg_lookup_dict` which partially contains this information - but it seems to be missing some information:

```
{
    'domain_kwargs': ('column', 'row_condition', 'condition_parser'),
    'success_kwargs': ('value_set', 'mostly', 'parse_strings_as_datetimes'),
    'default_kwarg_values': {
        'row_condition': None,
        'condition_parser': 'pandas',
        'mostly': None,
        'parse_strings_as_datetimes': None,
        'result_format': 'BASIC',
        'include_config': True,
        'catch_exceptions': False
    }
}
```

I also tried playing around with the `Validator` class but it only returns the complete list of names and no further information:

```py
from great_expectations.validator.validator import Validator
from great_expectations.execution_engine import SparkDFExecutionEngine, PandasExecutionEngine

validator_ = Validator(SparkDFExecutionEngine())

# 53 - the same for Pandas and Spark
print(len(validator_.list_available_expectation_types()))
```